# Rails 3.2.2 RVM System Wide Capistrano Install Can't Find Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm, capistrano, ubuntu-11.04

I really desperately need help with this issue and am more than a little lost.

I am trying to deploy a new production server using Capistrano Ext to allow for a staging and production server but it fails to run the bundle install --deployment successfully.

The cap staging deploy works fine to an existing Ubuntu system but the new server is a constant fail as follows

```
my-app$ sh -c 'cd /var/www/html/rails/myapp/releases/20120519174459&& export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin && bundle install --deployment'
  Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/......
  Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
  Installing rake (0.9.2.2) 
  Gem::LoadError: Could not find rubygems-bundler (>= 0) amongst []
  An error occured while installing rake (0.9.2.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
  Make sure that `gem install rake -v '0.9.2.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

In any other directory the ruby -v and rails -v produce the expected results

```
my-home$ ruby -v
 ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

my-home$ rails -v
 Rails 3.2.2
```

A listing of the local Gems on the production servershows they are all available

```
my-home$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.3, 3.2.2)
actionpack (3.2.3, 3.2.2)
active_utils (1.0.3)
activemerchant (1.21.0)
activemodel (3.2.3, 3.2.2)
activerecord (3.2.3, 3.2.2)
activeresource (3.2.3, 3.2.2)
activesupport (3.2.3, 3.2.2)
addressable (2.2.7)
ansi (1.4.2)
arel (3.0.2)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
bootstrap-sass (2.0.1)
builder (3.0.0)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.1.3, 1.0.21)
cancan (1.6.7)
capistrano (2.12.0, 2.11.2)
capistrano-ext (1.2.1)
cocaine (0.2.1)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.3, 1.2.0)
daemon_controller (1.0.0)
devise (2.0.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.3.2, 1.3.0)
faraday (0.7.6)
fastthread (1.0.7)
haml (3.1.4)
hashie (1.2.0)
highline (1.6.12, 1.6.11)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.3)
jquery-datatables-rails (1.9.1.3)
jquery-rails (2.0.2, 2.0.1)
jquery-ui-rails (0.3.0)
jruby-pageant (1.0.2)
json (1.7.3, 1.6.5)
libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86_64-linux)
mail (2.4.4)
metaclass (0.0.1)
mime-types (1.18, 1.17.2)
minitest (2.11.3)
mocha (0.10.5)
money (3.7.1)
multi_json (1.3.5, 1.1.0)
multipart-post (1.1.5)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.4.0, 2.3.0)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
nifty-generators (0.4.6)
oauth (0.4.5)
oauth2 (0.5.2)
omniauth (1.0.3)
omniauth-facebook (1.2.0)
omniauth-google (1.0.1)
omniauth-linkedin (0.0.6)
omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.0)
omniauth-twitter (0.0.8)
orm_adapter (0.0.6)
paperclip (3.0.2)
passenger (3.0.12)
polyamorous (0.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.3, 3.2.2)
railties (3.2.3, 3.2.2)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
RedCloth (4.2.9)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.0)
rvm (1.11.3.3)
sass (3.1.18, 3.1.15)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
simple_form (2.0.1)
simple_oauth (0.1.5)
sprockets (2.1.3, 2.1.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
squeel (1.0.1)
therubyracer (0.10.1, 0.9.10)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
timeliness (0.3.4)
treetop (1.4.10)
turn (0.9.4)
twitter (2.2.0)
tzinfo (0.3.33, 0.3.32)
uglifier (1.2.4, 1.2.3)
validates_timeliness (3.0.8)
warden (1.1.1)
will_paginate (3.0.3)
```

The rvm system wide on the server seems to be correct

```
my-home$ rvm list

  rvm rubies

  =* ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]

  # => - current
  # =* - current && default
  #  * - default

 my-home$ rvm info

  RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
  You need to change your terminal settings to allow shell login.
  Please visit https://rvm.io/workflow/screen/ for example.

  ruby-1.9.3-p194:

    system:
      uname:       "Linux totg01 2.6.38-14-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 27 20:04:55 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
      bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
      zsh:         " => not installed"

    rvm:
      version:      "rvm 1.13.5 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
      updated:      "4 days 2 hours 5 minutes 13 seconds ago"

     ruby:
       interpreter:  "ruby"
       version:      "1.9.3p194"
       date:         "2012-04-20"
       platform:     "x86_64-linux"
       patchlevel:   "2012-04-20 revision 35410"
       full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]"

    homes:
      gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
      ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"

    binaries:
      ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby"
      irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb"
      gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem"
      rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake"

    environment:
      PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
      GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
      GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global"
      MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
      IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/.irbrc"
      RUBYOPT:      ""
      gemset:       ""
```

But there is an epic fail in the application directory as there is nothing in ./vendor/bundle

```
app-dir$ ruby -v
 ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

app-dir$ rails -v
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `map!'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `materialize'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb:27:in `specs'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.0/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:41:in `candidate?'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.0/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:59:in `setup'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.0/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:9:in `<main>'
```

The system is Ubuntu 11.04 and ruby is installed using rvm system-wide with 1.93 as the default

The deploy.rb is as follows:

```
# This has been added due to multi deployment staging
set :stages, %w(staging production)
set :default_stage, "staging"

require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

default_run_options[:pty] = true 

set :user, 'appuser'
set :application, "app"
set :keep_releases, 10

set :deploy_to, "/var/www/html/rails/#{application}"
set :repository,  "appuser@gitserver:/myapps/rails/#{application}.git"
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}
set :scm, :git 
set :branch, 'master'
set :scm_verbose, true
set :use_sudo, false

# This has been added due to multi deployment staging
# since :domain is defined in another file (staging.rb and production.rb),
# we need to delay its assignment until they're loaded
set(:domain) { "#{domain}" }
role(:web) { domain }
role(:app) { domain }
role(:db, :primary => true) { domain }

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
  desc "cause Passenger to initiate a restart"
  task :restart do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
  desc "reload the database with seed data"
  task :seed do
    run "cd #{current_path}; rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production"
  end
end

before "deploy:assets:precompile", :bundle_install

after "deploy:update_code", :bundle_install
desc "install the necessary prerequisites"
task :bundle_install, :roles => :app do
  run "cd #{release_path}&& export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin && bundle install --deployment"
  run "cp -Rf #{shared_path}/config/* #{release_path}/config/"
end
```

The other two staging and production files are ....

deploy/staging.rb

```
set :domain, "staging.myapp.com"
set :rails_env, "staging"
set :default_environment, {  
   'PATH' => "/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/local/bin"  
}
```

deploy/production.rb

```
set :domain, "production.myapp.com"
set :rails_env, "production"
set :default_environment, {  
  'PATH' => "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/mysql/bin"  
 }
```

So the fail is trying to bundle install --deployment in a newly delivered application directory. If bundle install --nodeployment is run it works fine!

What have I done wrong or not configured. I've spent 2 days trying to sort this out but it doen't seem to make any sense why thios won't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you had to miss the rvm instructions for capistrano: https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano/

just read them, I will advise you to use the gem version which basically will allow you to select proper ruby:

Installation:

```
gem install rvm-capistrano
```

Or add to Gemfile:

```
gem 'rvm-capistrano'
```

Example Capfile deploy.rb :

```
set :rvm_type, :system    # :user is the default
set :rvm_ruby_string, ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/.*\//,"") # Read from local system

require "rvm/capistrano"  # Load RVM's capistrano plugin.
```

But better go check the docs, as more options are available: https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano/

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. In the end I had to remove all gems, ruby instances and rvm then reinstall! I don't know what on earth went wrong during the install process. When that was done I could make the bundle install --deployment work from the command line using the rvm shell (as is done with the rvm-capistrano gem). When I added your solution it also worked with Capistrano, thanks very much for the ideas and this would have fixed the problem initially if I hadn't had a corrupted installation!

Comment: your initial problem was caused by `rubygems-bundler 1.0.0` - the new installation of rvm also pulled new version of it - `1.0.2` which has the problem fixed

Comment: You just ended hours of agony and confusion.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Don't* use rvm1/capistrano3 or rvm/capistrano; *don't* set :pty.
2. Change `~/.rvmrc` for the runner user, on the server, to this — note that it has to come *before* the line where it kills itself when not running interactively:

```bash
# get rvm for non-interactive shells (eg capistrano) too
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
export BASH_ENV=$HOME/.bashrc
export rvm_is_not_a_shell_function=0

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```